# How can I extract multiple items and keep them as one json structure

Tags: jq

I have an example JSON of

```
{
  "reason": "TCP FINs",
  "bytes": "1759",
  "duration": "0:00:00",
  "dest": {
    "interface": "inside",
    "ip": "192.168.2.2",
    "port": "88"
  },
  "source": {
    "interface": "outside",
    "ip": "10.1.5.1",
    "port": "60470"
  },
  "connection-id": "400508768",
  "proto": "TCP",
  "hostname": "192.168.1.1",
  "timestamp": "Apr 28 13:00:01",
  "event.tags": [ "cisco", "ASA-6-302014" ]
 }
```

and I want to extract out the source and dest sections, but as one object.

```
{
  "dest": {
    "interface": "inside",
    "ip": "192.168.2.2",
    "port": "88"
  },
  "source": {
    "interface": "outside",
    "ip": "10.1.5.1",
    "port": "60470"
  }
}
```

If I do jq '.source,.dest" then I get two different objects

```
"dest": {
  "interface": "inside",
  "ip": "192.168.2.2",
  "port": "88"
}

"source": {
  "interface": "outside",
  "ip": "10.1.5.1",
  "port": "60470"
}
```

it's more obvious if you use -c because they come out as two different lines

As a more advanced stage, I would like to be able to get just part of this (the IP addresses) without the other data, but still as an object

```
{
  "dest": {
    "ip": "192.168.2.2",
  },
  "source": {
    "ip": "10.1.5.1",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
jq '{ "dest": .dest,  "source": .source }'
```

or for your final form:

```
jq '{ "dest": { "ip": .dest.ip },  "source": { "ip": .source.ip } }'
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "dest": {
    "ip": "192.168.2.2"
  },
  "source": {
    "ip": "10.1.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: next step, is there a way to filter and still get both sections? adding |map(select(.port == "88")) to the end of it only gives me the dest (and .dest.port == 88 didn't give me anything)

Comment: Since you're mapping to properties of the same name, you can simply do `{ dest, source }`.